# Uniquely complemented lattice that is non-modular

Tags: examples-counterexamples, lattice-orders

I'm looking for an explicit example of a uniquely complemented lattice that is non-modular, since neither of the two non-modular lattices described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice) at wikipedia have this property.

Thanks.

Comment: An [atomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_(order_theory)) uniquely complemented lattice is boolean, so your example would have to be non-atomic. There are exercises in Gratzer's Lattice Theory book in Chapter 3 (latest edition) about this. I don't have it in front of me so I can't give you the exact page. Sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We know that uniquely complemented lattices that are non-modular exist. This follows from the celebrated [result by Dilworth (pdf)](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1945-057-01/S0002-9947-1945-0012263-6/S0002-9947-1945-0012263-6.pdf). As far as I know, we do not know how to exhibit a concrete example, all the known constructions use some sort of complicated colimit. See the
[Graetzers paper in Notices (pdf)](http://www.ams.org/notices/200706/tx070600696p.pdf) for a general overview of results concerning unique complementation and much more.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading Gratzer's article right now.