# Example of a lattice which has at most 1 complement for its every element but it is not distributive.

Tags: lattice-orders

I know that-

> If a lattice is distributive then its every element has either 0 or 1
>   complement.

But Is it's converse true?

I am not able to find an example of a lattice which has at most 1 complement for its every element but it is not distributive.
Please give an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lattice in which each element has at most one complement may have elements with no complement at all.
It is rather easy to come up with non-distributive lattices with that property, even if we require that there is at least one pair of elements which are complements of one another.
For example, take a bounded, non-distributive lattice, in which no element except $0$ and $1$ has a complement.
For a less trivial example, one in which there are other pairs of complements, take the following example:

[image]

Here $\langle 0,1\rangle$ and $\langle a,b\rangle$ are the only pairs of complements, and the lattice is not distributive, since it has $M_3$ as a sublattice ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Characteristic_properties)).

If you're looking for a non-distributive lattice in which **every** element has a unique complement, that is not easy to point out.
I believe that there is no finite such lattice, but basically [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/610513/303170) tells that it exists (even non-modular).
Actually every lattice is a sublattice of a lattice with unique complements ([Dilworth's paper on this](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1945-057-01/S0002-9947-1945-0012263-6/S0002-9947-1945-0012263-6.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Means, there are many such lattices exist with every element has at most one complement, but they contain $M_3 \ or \ N_5$ as sublattice. Another Example is ($N$,|) where N = {0,1,2,3,4...........}
I will read Dilworth's paper and Gratzer's article for more detail :)

Comment: @user9014873 No, $(\mathbb N,|)$ is distributive. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060198/show-natural-numbers-ordered-by-divisibility-is-a-distributive-lattice). It has two answers more or less similar.