# Unique Complemented lattice which is not distributive lattice!

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I know that :
"if a distributive lattice is also complemented lattice then lattice should only have unique complement"
but i am not able to find a case where *A lattice is uniquely complemented but not distributive lattice*.
I am also aware about the Dilworth's theorem that "**Every lattice is a sub-lattice of some uniquely complemented lattice**", but even so, if we take any non distributive lattice (say L) which has non unique complement and according to Dilworth's theorem, L is part of a bigger uniquely complemented lattice(say L'), but still we cannot say anything about the lattice L' being non-distributive lattice, it may nor may not be distributive lattice, then how are we sure that lattice L' is uniquely complemented but not distributive lattice.?, i am not able to find an example to prove this!
I hope i was clear with my question!

Comment: If $L'$ were distributive then $L$ would be distributive too since it's a sublattice.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, sorry, edited my question, I meant to say that how are we sure that L' is non distributive lattice given that its sub-lattice(L) is non distributive but non uniquely complemented lattice!

Comment: It is immediate from the definitions that if $L'$ were distributive then $L$ would be distributive too, given that $L$ is a sublattice of $L'$.

Comment: It is given to us that L is non-distributive and is non uniquely complemented lattice, and because L is sub-lattice of L', i want to ask, how can we conclude that L' is also non-distributive lattice or distributive lattice!?

Answer (score 5):

There are (at least two) related questions on this site.

[The first one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814774/example-of-a-lattice-which-has-at-most-1-complement-for-its-every-element-but-it?rq=1) asks for a weaker property: is there a non-distributive lattice in which every element has at most one complement?

The [second one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608583/uniquely-complemented-lattice-that-is-non-modular?noredirect=1&lq=1), proposed by @goblinGONE asks for an apparently stronger property: is there a uniquely complemented lattice that is non-modular?
The [positive answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/610513) given by Gejza Jenča, that I invite you to upvote, gives a key reference, namely [Grätzer's survey paper in Notices (pdf)](http://www.ams.org/notices/200706/tx070600696p.pdf). In this paper, Theorem 1 states that a uniquely complemented modular lattice is distributive. It follows from this theorem that your question is actually a duplicate of @goblinGONE's question. Grätzer gives several solutions to your question in Section 2, but, as he doesn't know any simple example, he concludes with the following remarks:

> All known examples of nondistributive uniquely complemented lattices
> are freely generated, one way or another. Is there a construction of a
> nondistributive uniquely complemented lattice that is different?
>
> In the same vein, is there a “natural” example of a nondistributive
> uniquely complemented lattice from geometry, topology, or whatever
> else?

Comment: I think it is remarkable the paragraph in that Grätzer's paper before your citation: "It is interesting how little we know about a subject on which we have published so many papers. Ask any question and probably we do not know the answer. Let me mention a (very) few of my favorite ones." It's a testimony to the difficulty of the task...